# Continuity of Multivariable function

Tags: calculus

While doing revision I stumbled upon this problem:

Is this function continuous at the origin?

$$
f_3(x,y) =
 \begin{cases}
 \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}, & \text{if }(x,y)\not= (0,0) \\
0, & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}
$$

The answer is yes, but how do I prove it?

Sincere thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $u=(x,y) \ne 0=(0,0)$ we have
$$
|f_3(0)-f_3(u)|=|f_3(u)| \le \frac{|x|^3+|y|^3}{|u|_2^2}
\le \frac{2|u|_2^3}{|u|_2^2}=2|u|_2.
$$
For every $\epsilon>0$, if $|u|_2<\epsilon/2$ then $|f_3(0)-f_3(u)|<\epsilon$, i.e.
$f_3(u) \to f_3(0)=0$ as $u \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

This function is continuous at (0,0).
Consider the function in polar form,put $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$ in the given function, you will get $f(r,\theta) = r(cos\theta-sin\theta)(1+sin\theta.cos\theta)$.
As $x \to 0$ and $y \to 0$, limits in polar coordinates becomes $r \to 0$ and no limit on $\theta$ , but as  $r \to 0$, your function $f(r,\theta) = r(cos\theta-sin\theta)(1+sin\theta.cos\theta) \to 0$ whatsoever value $\theta$ takes.Therefore,$limit_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2} =0$ and the exact value at (0,0) is also $0$, hence the function is continuous at $(0,0)$.